# Removing App because it it violates the device and network abuse policy

Tags: android, google-play, icons, google-play-console

Starting from June 24th, 2019 Google started to delete apps which doesn't fit his new conditions; for example, all icons should to be square.

My app was deleted, too and Google sent me this e-mail:

> After review, myApp name, your App, has been removed from Google Play
> because it violates the device and network abuse policy. The large
> dimensions of your app's launcher icon negatively impacts performance
> of some user devices.
>
> Next Steps
>
> 1. Make changes to your app icon to bring your app into compliance. Your app’s launcher icon size must not exceed 2048 x 2048.
> 2. Read through the Device and Network Abuse policy for more details, and make sure your app complies with all policies listed in the
>    Developer Program Policies.
> 3. Sign in to your Play Console and submit the policy compliant update.

I have made all of this more than one time and they always deleted my app the next day.

My icon is now: 512*512 PNG, 32bit-color, 34,14 KB

I tried to use Image asset from Android Studio, and also tried to make my icon by myself.

All of this solutions got refused:

- android:icon="@drawable/icon"
- android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"

I think the problem now is not related to my icon, but I don't know what it is?

Comment: Can you also mention a bit about the type of the application app name or icon image or what your app does so that we can also take into account other reasons into account ? It is probably due to the size if you have not provided proper sizes as described in the answer

Comment: my app should to be able to communicate with NFC tag.
To read and write on Tags. it means my App need a premission to use NFC.
and it need also a premission to access the memory of device.
do you mean a size of luncher Image?

Comment: [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en) for support you can chat or email them

Comment: Chat support is currently not available.
and I already send them two e-mails, and waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got the answer, but I will say what I tried .

I were uploading a new version every time I need to change to notify them that they should to see the changes , and that was false .It is enough to to submit the update if you need just to change something in play console.

then I read some where that I should to look to all tracks alpha, beta, internal test, not just the production track.
and I did it and delete an old version from test track. and resubmit the update. but it dosn't help in my case.

the problem was *advanced managed Google Play features* 
you can find it in 
**store presence**

-pricing and distreibution

-managed google play

you should simply to check in the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Launcher icons

48 × 48 (mdpi)
72 × 72 (hdpi)
96 × 96 (xhdpi)
144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
512 × 512 (Google Play store) referenced from [iconhandbook](https://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/)

store all your different sizes launcher icons *(.png)* in respective mipmap folders. eg. 48*48 should go in mdpi as shown in image  below:
[image: mipmap folders]

> If you are publishing your app on Google Play, you will also need to
>   provide a 512 x 512 pixel, high-resolution application icon in the
>   developer console at upload time. This icon will be used in various
>   locations on Google Play and does not replace your launcher icon.

[referenced ui_guidelines doc](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html) which means 512* 512 is not for launcher icon but will be used on Google Play for your app. Provide mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi as well for launcher icons.

Comment: I use exactly the same file, I even "as I mention in the post" I used "Image asset" tool , it will creat all this files automaticlly.
the point for 512*512 pixel in developer console, I have edit it , and used the asked size, then I uploded my update .
But today I have got exactly the same E-mail.

Comment: if its not the size then it might be something else related to the application. check [device-network-abuse](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/device-network-abuse/). I hope you are using app name and icon image related to your application theme and not misleading as per Developer Program Policies.